# Rebuilding nginx with http_image_filter_module, how to correctly install the GD library in Windows and make it visible to other applications?

Tags: perl, nginx, gd, msys

I am currently trying to rebuild nginx with the http_image_filter_module but configuration has a problem locating the GD library.

Having followed the guide at: [Compile NGINX with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486482/compile-nginx-with-visual-studio/22649559#22649559) I finally managed to compile nginx with custom modules using MSYS and Strawberry Perl. I am only interested in generating the nginx.exe for now so only doing part 1 of the guide.  When trying to compile with the http_image_filter_module(requires GD library) using the following:

```
auto/configure --with-cc=cl --builddir=objs --prefix= --conf-path=conf/nginx.conf --pid-path=logs/nginx.pid --http-log-path=logs/access.log --error-log-path=logs/error.l
og --sbin-path=nginx.exe --http-client-body-temp-path=temp/client_body_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=temp/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=temp/fastcgi_temp --with-cc-opt
=-DFD_SETSIZE=1024 --with-pcre=objs/lib/pcre-8.39 --with-zlib=objs/lib/zlib-1.2.8 --with-openssl=objs/lib/openssl-1.0.2j --with-select_module --with-http_ssl_module --with
-http_image_filter_module
```

it presents the following error:

```
checking for OS
 + MINGW32_NT-6.2 1.0.19(0.48/3/2) i686
 + using Microsoft Visual C++ compiler
 + cl version: 19.00.24215.1 for x86
checking for MINGW32_NT-6.2 specific features
checking for GD library ... not found
checking for GD library in /usr/local/ ... not found
checking for GD library in /usr/pkg/ ... not found
checking for GD library in /opt/local/ ... not found

auto/configure: error: the HTTP image filter module requires the GD library.
You can either do not enable the module or install the libraries.
```

I have ran the setup program of the GD package from: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gd.htm but i'm obviously missing a step or two for it to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2):

To solve it:

1. open file auto/feature in nginx source dir, change

   `if [ -x $NGX_AUTOTEST ]; then`

   to

   `if [ YES ]; then`
2. open file auto/lib/libgd/conf in nginx source dir, add code at Proper location

```
    if [ $ngx_found = no ]; then
    
    ngx_feature="GD library in custom path" # 指定libgd头文件位置 ngx_feature_path="/e/thirdparty_source/libgd-2.2.4/src" # 指定libgd库文件位置和库文件 ngx_feature_libs="-L/e/thirdparty_source/gdbuild -lgd" . auto/feature
    
    fi
```