# Nginx, some problems after compilation (file/folder/processus creation)

Tags: nginx

I am trying to compile Nginx with Visual Studio 2015, as a project. I followed this tutorial : [Compile NGINX with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486482/compile-nginx-with-visual-studio/22649559#22649559) , which worked pretty well (even if it was made for VS 2010).

I was finally able to launch nginx.exe but the webserver doesn't work yet, several things :

1. Release mode

The program exits with the messages :

```
The thread 0x25ac has exited with code 2 (0x2).
The thread 0xe64 has exited with code 2 (0x2).
The thread 0x1a60 has exited with code 2 (0x2).
The program '[13872] nginx.exe' has exited with code 2 (0x2).
```

The error.log file contains :

```
2018/05/28 15:26:09 [crit] 13872#4024: CreateProcess("my\nginx\path\Nginx\Release\nginx.exe") failed (5: FormatMessage() error:(15100))
```

2. Debug Mode

The program exits with the messages :

```
The thread 0x18a8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x3064 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x2bbc has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[6868] Nginx.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

The error.log file contains :

```
2018/05/28 14:14:25 [emerg] 13152#14248: CreateDirectory() "my/nginx/path/Nginx/Debug/temp/client_body_temp" failed (123: FormatMessage() error:(15100))
```

Here's the arborescence of my/nginx/path/Nginx/Debug/ and my/nginx/path/Nginx/Release/ :

```
nginx.exe
conf/
    nginx.conf
    a bunch of other conf files
html/
    index.html
logs/
    error.log
    acces.log
    nginx.pid
temp/
    client_body_temp/
```

Note : I myself created the different files and folder, the program was unable to do it.

3. nginx.conf

Last, I'm unable to modify the path of my error.log in nginx.conf. When I try to do it, it seems to have no effect at all.The command

```
error_log logs/error_bis.log;
```

does not create error_bis.log or does not write in it if I create the file.

Note : the prefix path is set when I launch nginx.exe with the command argument

```
-p my/nginx/path/Nginx/Debug
```

And last thing, I have the admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem.

CreateDirectory was calling CreateDirectoryW instead of CreateDirectoryA beacause UNICODE was defined. An unsigned char* was given to the function instead of a LPWSTR.

I just had to set "Character Set" (in Property->General->Project Defaults) from "Unicode" to "No set". Everything works now.